# Why is it OkHttp post method sends get request instead of post request?

Tags: java, android, post, get, okhttp

I am working in android app that needs to get a token from a web api through POST request, I am using OkHttp library version 2.3.0 but strangely the post method is executing GET request as the result I am getting 405 status code which is method not allowed response from the server.

Here's my code.

```
public static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

public String executePOST(){

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    .
    .
    .
    .

    String url = API_URL + "/oauth/access_token/";
    String strResponse = null;

    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonBody);

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url(url)
          .post(body)
          .build();

    Response response;

    try {

        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        strResponse = response.body().string(); 

      } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return strResponse;
   }
```

When I debug the code the response object has this content...

[image]

Any idea what's the problem with this? What is the possible work around for this one? Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried removing the **/** at the end of your URL? I came across a similar issue once and doing that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 7):

I had this kind of problem when i send POST to **http**:// and not **https**://.

I suppose, it automatically redirected me to https:// where the method type was lost.

Answer (score 1):

Note the `priorResponse()` member of your HTTP response. Your `POST` request is being redirected, and the webserver is rejecting the redirected request. It’s likely that whatever webserver is doing the redirect should return a 307 or 308 (which retains the request method) instead of whatever redirect response code it's returning currently.

Comment: This was happening to me too ... and it was because I was including "www" in the API_URL

Answer (score 1):

My issue was an extra slash in the URL, it was like this before

> mysite.com/api/v1/question/attend/

it worked after removing the slash like below

> mysite.com/api/v1/question/attend

Answer (score 0):

You need to set call post when you build your request, like this:

```
  String postBody = "postBody\n";

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://api.github.com/markdown/raw")
        .post(RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN, postBody))
        .build();
```

But i see, that you are calling post... maybe the media_type should be different.

```
  public static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN
      = MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown; charset=utf-8");
```

but you probably need this one:

```
  public static final MediaType JSON
      = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Comment: Ok I will try it... :)

Comment: what is that MEDIA_TYPE_MARKDOWN constant? Where can I obtain it?

Comment: Yeah but what should I use among the two? I am using the JSON MediaType.

Comment: It looks like the library is choosing which method to use based on mediatype... but it is working badly. try with markdown, and see if server will accept that.